# remove multiple characters based on carrier position

Tags: r

I have the following list element. It contains raw text and columns are based on character length. The first row is always 427 characters wide. the rest of rows are 375 characters wide.

I require to delete the last 9 characters of each one of the rows that are 375 characters wide. that would be carrier positions 367 to 375

```
df = structure(list(X1 = c("00000104900914254       1BBVA SEGUROS DE VIDA COLOMBIA S.A.                                                                                                                    NI800240882       0ACRA 11 87-51                            001130000000   7777777   LUZ.MARTINEZ@xxxx.COM                                       2021-042021-04-22U                                                  0004900000000213P0000000000022021-04-21", 
"00000012CC1130000000      MORENO              REINA                         DANIELA                                           MORENO              AYALA                         LUIS                ALBERTO                       CC63000000        03N1N68001      300004542630.08000000036400000000000                              000454263                               000908526", 
"00000022CC63000000        MURILLO             ESCALANTE                     KELLY               JOHANA                                                                                                                                              08N1N68001      300009085260.08000000072700000000000                              000908526                               000908526"
)), .Names = "X1", row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `sub` or even `gsub`:

```
df$X2 <- sub("^(.{366}).{9}$", "\\1", df$X1, perl = TRUE)
nchar(df$X2)
[1] 427 366 366
```

With this code, the first row was maintained at 427 characters while the rest were reduced to 366

Answer (score 2):

We can use `nchar` with `min` on the `substr`

```
library(dplyr)
out <-  df %>%
   mutate(X1 = substr(X1, 1, min(nchar(X1))))
```

---

If we need to change the rest of the rows keeping the first row same

```
out <- df %>%
        mutate(X1 = replace(X1, -1, substr(X1[-1], 1, 367)))


nchar(out$X1)
#[1] 427 367 367
```

NOTE: `substr` should be the fastest option

---

Or using `base R`

```
df$X1 <- substr(df$X1, 1, min(nchar(df$X1)))
```

Answer (score 2):

This is also another solution to be added to already great ones:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

DT %>%
  mutate(X1 = ifelse(nchar(X1) != 427, str_sub(X1, 1L, 367L), X1)) %>%
  mutate(nc = nchar(X1)) %>%
  select(nc)

# A tibble: 3 x 1
     nc
  <int>
1   427
2   367
3   367
```

Last two lines of code are for tested purposes and therefore can be omitted.